# Slide Down Div on Hover, have Div Stay on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to achive something like on [Shopify.ca](http://shopify.ca), where you can hover over a div to expand another directly below, with a sliding effect. When you're hovering over the expanded div, it will stay there. Then retract when you mouseover anywhere other than the expanded div.

[image]

Here it the JSFiddle I have so far, the problem is the div disappears when you hover over the expanded one.

Comment: My apologies, I've forgotten to add the JsFiddle. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcs9D/1/

You will probably want to adapt that to your code and not just blindly copy and paste.

My implementation uses a combination of CSS and jQuery.

Basically, you have three layers:

1. An outer container that encompasses all of the questions so they all slide down at once
2. An inner container for each question which contains both the question and its answer
3. Any content within the inner container (the question and answer)

The only thing you really need JavaScript for is the slide down effect. That's accomplished when you hover over the first layer or outer container.

```
$('.faq').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.question p').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.question p').slideUp();
});
```

The rest of the effects you can manage with CSS:

```
.faq
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}

.faq:before,
.faq:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.faq:after {
    clear: both;
}

.faq .question
{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}

.faq .question p
{
    display: none;
    color: #555;
}

.faq .question:hover p
{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: A big thanks Sunjay, I understand how it works now. The fiddle however, retracts too soon when you hover over it fast (or hover and move your mouse in it fast). How would I make it so that it has a time limit before the div expands again?

Comment: You could make the animation faster. Or you could add a callback to the slideDown() call which sets a boolean when the animation is complete. That boolean could then be used to determine whether slideUp() is called on mouse leave. That second approach may introduce some bugs though, so it's probably just best to leave it as is. Your users will figure things out as long as the animation is fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

To have the expanded div remain expanded when you hover over it, you should make the two elements (trigger and expander) be siblings which are contained in a single wrapper element. For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Some Title</div>
  <div class="expand">The text you want to expand out</div>
</div>
```

Then you would apply the expansion when `.wrapper` is hovered rather than the title, and it will remain expanded when you move your mouse from the title over to the expanded text.